# Simple addition in Javascript

Tags: javascript

It's simple addition in Javascript. But I don't understand why result is 1510 instead of 15+10.

```
<script>
function doCalc(){
    with (document.calc){
    sum1.value = orderin.value+ ordercheck.value
    }
}
</script>
<form method="post" name="calc" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input checked="checked" value="0" name="orderin" type="RADIO" onChange="doCalc()">+0
    <input value="15" name="orderin" type="RADIO" onChange="doCalc()">+15
    <br><br>
    <input id="ordercheck1" checked="checked" value="0" name="ordercheck" type="RADIO" onChange="doCalc()">+0
    <input id="ordercheck2" value="10" name="ordercheck" type="RADIO" onChange="doCalc()">+10
    <br><br>
    TOTAL: <input size="7" value="0" name="sum1" readonly="readonly" border="0">
    <input onClick="doCalc()" value="TOTAL" name="button" type="button">
</form>
```

Comment: this is javascript, not java. They are completely unrelated languages. Please change the title with the correct language.

Comment: As suggested by @ThePcLuddite it has nothing to do with java , kindly remove java from tittle and body

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953939/how-to-force-addition-instead-of-concatenation-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Javascript variable can hold every type (string and a number). You are trying to add two strings. Try using this:

```
sum1.value = parseInt(orderin.value,10) + parseInt(ordercheck.value,10)
```

parseInt will try to turn a string into a number. The 10 indicates you want to turn the number into decimal scale. More about parseInt [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 0):

By default output of input is string/literal in javascript, hence its getting concanated. You need to parse it into int.

```
 sum1.value = parseInt(orderin.value)+ parseInt(ordercheck.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do `+` when one (or both) of your variables are considered a string. Make sure to always parseInt(variable) first when you aren't sure!
Usually values selected from the DOM (user input from text fields and such) are considered strings.

```
// these are ints
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
var c = a + b; // c is 15

// notice the ""-notation, these are strings
var x = "5"; 
var y = "10";
var z = x + y; // z is 510

// just do this to fix it:
var z = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y) // z is 15
```

In your case:

```
sum1.value = parseInt(orderin.value) + parseInt(ordercheck.value)
```