# what's the meaning of the follow syntax var: " div:nth-child(" + $n + ")"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

More specifically, why do I need the + sign on both sides of my variable ? 
Here there is an example , for more context of what I'm asking:
[link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0cefc4/puzzle-game-using-jquery855/)

Comment: documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) read about it

Comment: `why do I need the + sign on both sides of my variable?` because you're concatenating a string.

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively defining a CSS selector, [see docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

The selector must be a string, `$n` here is a variable and the `+` signs concatenate (join together) the string and the variable.

Answer (score 0):

`+` operator use for `concat` two string in `javascript` and `jQuery`

Example:

```
var a = 'Avanish';
var b = a+' Kumar';
console.log('Value of a---->'+a);
console.log('Value of b---->'+b);
```

output is

```
 Value of a---->Avanish
 Value of b---->Avanish Kumar
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

[How to force addition instead of concatenation in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953939/how-to-force-addition-instead-of-concatenation-in-javascript)