# How can I add 2 variables' numerical values together in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I do:
var answer=a+b

if a was 4 and b was 5 then my answer comes out as 45. How can i get them to numerically add. I can do all other operations(*/-) but not add. Ik its a stupid question but im new and trying to lean

var prea,a,answer2,answer4,answer3,b,preb,answer1;

```
prea=document.getElementById("form1") ;
a=prea.elements["first"].value;
preb=document.getElementById("form1") ;
b=preb.elements["second"].value;
answer1=a*b;
answer2=a-b;
answer3=a/b;
answer4=a+b;
document.write("Multiplication:"+answer1); 
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Subtraction:"+answer2);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Division:"+answer3);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Add:"+answer4);
```

Comment: parseInt :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: You're surely operating on text input fields; any text input field's value is [a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). Because you need [a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) instead, try to cast a string to a number: `Number(a) + Number(b)`.

Comment: Welcome to the _wonderful_ world of javascript :)

Comment: Also, don’t use `document.write`!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force addition instead of concatenation in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953939/how-to-force-addition-instead-of-concatenation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Number(a) + Number(b)` to calculate them. If you using strings instead of numbers, you just concatinate them instead of adding.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp

Comment: Why are `a` and `b` strings? Why do the "other operations" work?

Comment: If you are using other operators like *, / or -, there is an auto conversion from string operands to numbers. It just works, because these operators don't do anything else. The + operator instead is used for concatination and also for addition and since javascript isn't well developed, the + operator is used for concatination per default.

Comment: @Tyr “auto conversion” is commonly referred to as “coercion”. JavaScript isn’t “not well developed” just because `+` has multiple semantics.

Comment: This (without the opinion-based part) should be part of your answer and not buried in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are being declared as strings.  You need to type cast them as an integer value to properly add them using `parseInt(string)`.

The reason all the other operators work is because they will try to type juggle.  However, javascript uses `+` for both numerical addition and string concatenation.  So you have to explicitly use integer types if you want the result to be a summation.

Comment: [MDN: Dynamic typing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) _"JavaScript is a loosely typed or a dynamic language. Variables in JavaScript are not directly associated with any particular value type, and any variable can be assigned (and re-assigned)  values of all types"_