# Concatenating numbers instead off adding them together

Tags: javascript, html

Having read for hours on the web and tried various things I am lost as to the answer to my problem. I want to be able to check a checkbox and get the value from an input box. ie If more than 1 checkbox is checked the values (both £100) would produce a sum of £200. I am getting "100100"!

My html table is produced with PHP with value '$price' from a mySQL database as a DECIMAL (10,2):

```
<html>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input name='payInvoice' type='checkbox' onchange='add()'></td>
<td><input id='amountToPay' value=$price></td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

and javascript:

```
<script>
function add(){
var payOff = " "
    document.getElementById('poff').value = "";   
var payoff = document.getElementsByName("payInvoice");
    for (var i=0; i<payoff.length; i++){
    if (payoff[i].checked == true){
    amount = document.getElementById("amountToPay");
    $s = parseInt(amount.value);
    payOff += ($s) ;   
    document.getElementById('poff').value = payOff;
        } 
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force addition instead of concatenation in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953939/how-to-force-addition-instead-of-concatenation-in-javascript)

Comment: Seems that payOff is being treated as a string

Answer (score 1):

Change `var payOff = " "` to `var payOff = 0` and it will work.You are adding string to integers hence its not working.

So when you write `payOff += $(s);` you are actually doing `payOff = (" " + interger)` which is basically string concatenation hence you will always get a string back

Comment: Thank you!! It had to be something so simple!