# Unable to add two variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with javascript and right now trying to sum(add/plus) two variables but right now instead of "addition"(plus) variables are "concate",Here is my current code

```
var first = this.value; // getting value "5"
var second =$("#earning").val(); // getting value "2"
var final_value =first + second;
M
```

y expected result is "7"(5+2) but its giving me "52",how can i fix this ?

Comment: Nothing surprising here! If strings are present as operands instead of integers, they are concatenated. Do `var final_value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second)`

Comment: First result on Google. Does this answer your question? [How to force addition instead of concatenation in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953939/how-to-force-addition-instead-of-concatenation-in-javascript)